# Android переход между активити без перегрузки экрана?

Tags: android, activity

Добрый день.

Есть три активности. Как организовать переходы между активити без перезагрузки активити? С помощью чего это можно сделать? Или чем заменить несколько activity?

Comment: кем это имеется ввиду и в связи с чем это поимели ввиду? Вопрос должен содержать такое описание проблемы, которое делает понятной вашу проблему другим. Ваш вопрос не делает вашу проблему понятной другим.

Comment: @pavlofff Извиняюсь, имеется ввиду без перезагрузки активити при переходе между ними.

Comment: Что вы назваете "перезагрузкой"? Когда вы открываете следующую активити, то предыдущие остаются. Когда последняя завершает работу, опять становится активной предыдущая.

Comment: У меня три предположения, что вам нужно. Первое - возможно, вы пытаетесь вспомнить слово Fragment. Они позволяют организовать смену содержимого интерфейса полностью, не перезагружая активити. Второе - у вас где-то в активити запускается долгая операция (запрос к серверу, например), и все неудобства из-за нее. Тогда нужно найти болеее правильное место для запуска. И третье предположение - вам не нравится то, что активити может быть разрушена и создана заново. От этого избавиться невозможно, вам придется это обрабатывать, так как это - естественное явление в андроиде.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я вас понял, вы хотите реализовать что-то на подобие перелистывания экранов, тогда ViewPager вам в помощь, а вот и [официальный гайд от google](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).
Если это не то, что вы искали, то в комментарии tse было сказано о фрагментах, при помощи них вы свможете реализовать задуманное